# Python subprocess giving error "ResourceWarning: subprocess <number> is still running" in spite of python being closed

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python script that opens another python script via subprocess shell as following:

```
Popen('python {}'.format("script_name.py"), shell=True)
```

I communicate with this program using localhost socket communication and the program terminates upon disconnecting.

Whenever I unittest a part of my program that uses this subprocess command I get the following error:

```
ResourceWarning: subprocess <number> is still running
```

is there a "clean" way to terminate a subprocess to prevent this warning from occurring?

Comment: why are you calling subprocess.call onto another python file? why cant you just import it and execute it?

Comment: @AlbinPaul I am using the pygame library in both instances, but pygame only allows one window per python instance